# Swift unknown syntax in tutorial : let queryString = "INSERT INTO Heroes (name, powerrank) VALUES (?,?)"

Tags: swift, sqlite

By looking an introductory tutorial on how to use SQLite in Swift (in the iOS context), I saw the following line of code:

```
let queryString = "INSERT INTO Heroes (name, powerrank) VALUES (?,?)"
```

tutorial URL : https://www.simplifiedios.net/swift-sqlite-tutorial/

I don't understand if this is a Swift feature of something which will be parsed by SQL

It it some kind of string interpolation, like:

```
var s = "The value is \(value)"
```

Or is it something else?

Comment: Those are placeholders for the data to be sent separately, to avoid SQL injection. They are importantly **not** string interpolation. See https://bobby-tables.com/ and https://stackoverflow.com/q/60174/157957 etc

Comment: If it's not Swift and not SQL, then what is it?

Comment: I guess they are SQL, in a way - they are interpreted *by the database implementation* as "a piece of data will be provided separately for use here". As I say, read up about what "SQL Injection" is, and how they prevent it.

Comment: So, a SQL dialect of sorts...

Comment: If I were you, I'd worry less about trying to find a neat label for it, and more on learning how to use it correctly, which you will achieve by reading about how to prevent SQL Injection.

Answer (score 0):

This other tutorial sheds some light regarding the meaning of said syntax:

https://www.raywenderlich.com/6620276-sqlite-with-swift-tutorial-getting-started

It says:

Here, you define a value for the ? placeholder. The function’s name — sqlite3_bind_int() — implies you’re binding an Int to the statement.
The first parameter of the function is the statement to bind to, while the second is a non-zero-based index for the position of the ? you’re binding to. The third and final parameter is the value itself. This binding call returns a status code, but for now, you assume that it succeeds.